# Add multi-column data to WPF ListView in VB.NET 2008

Tags: wpf, vb.net, .net-3.5, wpfdatagrid

I've been searching and searching, but I haven't been able to find a halfway-decent way of adding multiple columns of data into a WPF VB.NET ListView.  The data I'm adding is not from a datasource.

I would like to add files and dates to the ListView while I'm searching for the files.

Here is the XAML for the ListView and the GridView added to it:

```
<Grid>
    <ListView Margin="0,101,0,0" 
              Name="dataListView">
        <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="myGridView">
            <GridViewColumn Width="225" 
                                Header="File Name" 
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding theName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="165" 
                                Header="Date/Time"
                                DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding theDay}"/>
        </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Here is the code-behind where I'm trying to add to the ListView:

```
Private Sub searchPath_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles searchPath.Click
    Dim dirInfo As New DirectoryInfo(sourcePath.Text)
    Dim theName, theDate As String

    dataListView.Items.Clear()
    For Each filInfo In dirInfo.GetFiles("*.QBB", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        dataListView.Items.Add(new {theName = filInfo.Name, theDate = filInfo.LastWriteTime})
    Next
End Sub
```

Please help me populate this ListView in WPF VB.NET 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem, how is it not working?

Comment: It won't allow me to add data to multiple columns.  I can add to the primary column, but the data won't add to the second column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to feel silly but the second column in your code-behind is called `theDate` but the second column in your XAML is bound to `theDay`.  Welcome to the perils of run-time databinding.  In the future have a look at the output window of the debug build for binding errors.

**Edit:**

This was actual a different question in disguise: *What is the syntax for anonymous types in Visual Basic?*

- [Anonymous Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

For example:

```
Dim product = New With {Key .Name = "paperclips", .Price = 1.29}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code review, but I'm still getting an error on the 'DataListView.Items.Add(new {...' line in the code-behind.  It's looking for a 'With' in there?  It won't compile without it.

Comment: The syntax is `New With { Key .theName = ...` see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

Comment: That did it!  Thank you, it was driving me crazy!  Especially since I haven't worked with WPF before.  Thanks for the info and the link!